# Why do I get an infinite digest error here?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I need to create groups of things that come as a flat array, so I can open and close grid rows using a CSS grid system.

Here's how my HTML looks:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in items | GroupsOf: 3" class="row">
    [show stuff]
</div>
```

And here's the filter I wrote to support this:

```
.filter('GroupsOf', function(){     
    //Takes an array of things and groups them into  
    // sub-arrays with numPerGroup things in each 
    return function(things, numPerGroup){

        var i, group = -1, groups = []          
        for(i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
            //if it's a new group:
            if(i % numPerGroup === 0){                  
                groups.push([])
                group++
            }
            groups[group].push(things[i])
        }
        return groups//
    }
})
```

Although things render as expected, I'm getting infinite digest error when this runs, and therefore not everything gets wired up properly. 
**Why do I get that error, and how do I fix the filter to work w/o erring?**

I'd really prefer to do this as a filter rather than grouping the data in the controller, but I'll go the later route if someone can explain to me why it's just not achievable as a filter.

Comment: Is the [show stuff] only showing the values without doing any additional processing?

Comment: You should post your traceback

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: Even if there's *nothing* in show stuff, I'm getting the error.

Comment: make sure to return before loop if data is loaded async or `things` will be undefined

Comment: This sort of chunking would be far better done in a service or controller . Need to realize how many times digests do get run. Or even use your filter in controller with `$filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use $filter in the controller( which is certainly more performant and fixes the infinite $digest loop issue) you can do :

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.items = [
    'one','two','three',
    'unos','dos','tres',
    'uno','due','tre'
    ]
    $scope.grouped = $filter('GroupsOf')($scope.items , 3)
    console.log($scope.grouped)
})
.filter('GroupsOf', function(){     
//Takes an array of things and groups them into  
// sub-arrays with numPerGroup things in each 
return function(things ,numPerGroup){
    var i, group = -1, res = []          
    for(i = 0; i < things.length ; i++){
        //if it's a new group:
        if(i % numPerGroup === 0){                  
            res.push([])
            group++
        }
        res[group].push(things[i])
    }
    return res
}
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<div ng-repeat="row in grouped" class="row">
    {{row}}
</div>


</div>
```

looking at the [infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) documentation it seems your problem is caused by

> .. binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called.

that should be the reason $digest never finds a clean state.